# Determine which player is on the move

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, class

I am trying to build a card game in python to get a little bit into OOP.
I am searching for a way to determine wchich player is on the move. The rule in the card game is that one of the four players is the dealer, and the next one is then the first to play a card.
I have searched for some ways to do that but I couldnt finde a solution for this.
At the moment I have something like this:

```
player_list = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

def func_turn(first_player):
    for i in range(len(player_list)): 

        if first_player + i == 4:
            first_player = 0
        player_list[first_player + i].play_card()
```

Is there a better way to do that something I can implement in the player class or some list functions I am not aware of?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

You can use some methods from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module to create the appropriate generator for your case. Let's work with the example list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Firstly, we want to [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) the list so that it keeps repeating. This will give us

```
>>> b = itertools.cycle(a)    # generator object that gives [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, ...]
```

Next, we want to skip ahead by a certain amount. This is your `first_player` variable and we want to take `n` elements where `n` is the number of players. We can accomplish this using the [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) method

```
>>> itertools.islice(b, 2, 2 + 4)   # generator object that gives [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

---

Putting this all together, you get

```
import itertools as it

def func_turn(start):
    for player in it.islice(it.cycle(player_list), start, start + len(player_list)):
        player.play_card()
```

### Method 2

You can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and its [rotate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method to update the player order after every turn

```
from collections import deque

player_list = deque([p1, p2, p3, p4])

def func_turn():
    for player in player_list:
        player.play_card()

    player_list.rotate(-1)    # will be deque([p2, p3, p4, p1]) after 1 rotation
```

Comment: Or a simple modulo! `player_order = [1, 2, 3, 4]; current_player = player_order[current_turn % len(player_order)]`

Comment: Yes but that would still require the use of `range(len(first_player))`

Comment: thank you very much, thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: And I used to use modulo, but I wanted to know some more general way because maybe in future i will do it by player name(str) or something.